# updating a macports installed program to the most recent revision

Tags: macos, emacs, git, version-control, macports

I general use macports to manage as much as I can---emacs, for example.  Just now a fix was implemented in emacs for a bug that's been bothering me.  Is it possible to incorporate the most recent emacs revision to my existing macports installation, or do I need to ditch the port, and install anew from (e.g.) the emacs git repository?

Comment: You could try and patch the bug in your local `.emacs`. Not a solution, I know, but might be a workaround.

Comment: @Dror how do you mean?

Comment: As I said, not a solution per se, but if you know what is the code fragment that fixes the bug you could place it in your `.emacs` file locally.

Answer (score 1):

This exact problem is why I switched from MacPorts to [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), which lets me build a current Emacs with this command (`--HEAD` means from the bzr/git source code; `--cocoa` means that it builds the Cocoa framework version, like the `emacs-app` target from MacPorts):

```
brew install --HEAD emacs --cocoa
```

The Homebrew Emacs port maintainers track the current release of Emacs, so you can drop the `--HEAD` choice if a release is adequate.

Comment: Thanks Mike!  Have you found any deficiencies in homebrew (vs. macports)?  And do you have a recommended way of switching?

Comment: @zhermes No, I haven't really run into problems. Everything that I was used to building from MacPorts was available in Homebrew. The Homebrew people think differently from MacPorts and won't replace OS-provided tools unless necessary. All I did was keep track of the ports I had installed (`port list`) and then install them with brew. Then I fixed my paths (Homebrew installs under /usr/local) and got comfortable before removing /opt.